# Using as-patterns not binding to the full List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Ok, maybe the title is a little confusing, but what I am trying to do is have a function like this: `f (a:b:c:d:is) = ...` but be able to refer to `a:b:c:d` without writing it again. As it turns out, I can't do something like `e@(a:b:c:d):is` and get the expected result. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll want to user the proper syntax, e@(a:b:c:d:is)

Comment: Oh I see what you're getting at. If you're using (e@(a:b:c:d):is), then it's a list of lists with d being the tail of the inner lists. I don't think you can help this with as patterns, since the parens for grouping will be necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I can think of is using [view patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns), like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
f (splitAt 4 -> (as@[a,b,c,d], is)) = is ++ [d,c,b,a] ++ as
```

Comment: You could avoid the language pragma by just using pattern guards.

  "f xs | (e@[a,b,c,d], is) <- splitAt 4 xs = e"

Comment: I was hoping for something as 'clean' as as-patterns, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that, one reason is that `a:b:c:d` is not a well-typed expression. By the binding in the definition of `f`, `a, b, c, d` all have the same type, say `t`, but the type of the list constructor is

```
(:) :: t -> [t] -> [t]
```

You can sort-of achieve what you want by binding `let foo = take 4 inputList`. Admittedly clunky, but I can't think of anything better off the top of my head.